# Unable to insert JQuery variable data using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert a particular variable string "date" into my database upon clicking of a button.

```
var date2 = curr_year + "-" + m_names[curr_month] + "-" + curr_date + "T" +
            curr_hour2 + ":" + curr_min + ":" + milli + " ";

var date = "<abbr class='timeago' title=" + date2 + "></abbr>";

var DATA = 'date=' + date;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "comment.php",
  data: DATA,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
  }
});
```

However the data does not seem to be sent to the php file and the database is not updated. Any advice would be excellent.

Comment: Are you sure the data isn't being sent, or is the PHP file generating errors? Try `var DATA = 'date='+encodeURIComponent(date)` instead -- [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> ### data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
> not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
> processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
> be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
> values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
> (described below).

So in other words, although `data` accepts a string, that string has to be in a JSON format.

Something like this would work better:

```
var DATA = { date: 'date=' + date };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pass your data like json Format,

```
  var date2 = curr_year + "-" + m_names[curr_month] + "-" + curr_date + "T" +
        curr_hour2 + ":" + curr_min + ":" + milli + " ";

  var date = "<abbr class='timeago' title=" + date2 + "></abbr>";

   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "comment.php",
           data: { 'data':"+date+" },
           cache: false,
           success: function(data){
          }
        });
```